# What is the Excel formula to countif text partially makes up a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Essentially, I am having trouble finding the formula to perform a countif in an array for text that partially comprises other cells in the array.

As an example, when searching for text "fire" in an array of "fire", "arcade fire", "firetruck", and "water", I'd want the formula to return a value of three. Have tried using countif and match to no avail.

Code I've tried includes:
MATCH("FIRE",B1:B4,1) where B1:B4 are the above strings. COUNTIF("FIRE",B1:B4). =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FIRE",B1:B4)),1,0) (this function is not ideal as it would not be counting).

Comment: show the formula that you've tried

Comment: MATCH("FIRE",B1:B4,1) where B1:B4 are the above strings. COUNTIF("FIRE",B1:B4). =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FIRE",B1:B4)),1,0) (this function is not ideal as it would not be counting).

Comment: Use the edit button to include that comment in the question. code isn't really legible in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this standard COUNTIF with a criteria wrapped in wildcards.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5, "*fire*")
```

[image]

Comment: This works - do you know how to make wildcards and cells interact (i.e. using *B1* as the second expression if "fire" is in cell B1).

Comment: `=COUNTIF(A1:A5, "*"&B1&"*")`

Comment: Thank you! This should solve all my headaches and avoid me having to mess about in Python.

Comment: alternate `=COUNTIF(A1:A5, TEXT(B1, "\*@\*"))`

Answer (score 1):

If the text "fire", "arcade fire", "firetruck" is in column A, such

```
A1 = fire
A2 = arcade fire
...
```

First add a column B, fill in with the following values:

```
B2 =ISNUMBER(SEARCH("fire",A2))
B3 =ISNUMBER(SEARCH("fire",A3))
......
```

then get your results by:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B5,"TRUE")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below, you cannot get the correct result using a single function line. Thus you have to first evaluate whether the text contains the correct string and then do a count on them:

[image]

Hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: Have a huge list of terms to perform this function on so was hoping there might be. Thanks - I'm sure I'll find a workaround with this advice.

Comment: I didn't spend too much time playing around with it but I did end up trying this but it didn't work: =COUNTIF(A1:A5, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("abc",A1:A5)))) Maybe if you can find a workaround post it on here so others may benefit from it as well. Thanks!